# Where is the yellow hue?

Tags: color, pstricks, inkscape

I took a `.svg` figure and converted it with `Inkscape` to a `pstricks` picture.
The figure has a five different background colors.
Its a color palette from yellow-white to red.
But the pstricks variant looses the yellow hue.

What is going on, and how can I adjust for this?

This is the original:

[image]

And this is the pstricks version
[image]

The `inkscape` `save as .tex` did in fact export different colors.
After noticing this, I entered the original colors manually.
The colors are:

```
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor1}{0.996078 0.952941 0.964706}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor2}{0.980392 0.882353 0.905882}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor3}{0.972549 0.74902 0.792157}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor4}{0.972549 0.65098 0.713725}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor5}{0.964706 0.513725 0.631373}
```

Comment: I guess this has something to do with the color space my display operates on and what is set in the various applications.
Is there a quick and concise introduction to my sort of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a matter of gamma. In my screens (both) this is a pinkish-white to pink sequence.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{bgcolor1}{rgb}{0.996078, 0.952941, 0.964706}
\definecolor{bgcolor2}{rgb}{0.980392, 0.882353, 0.905882}
\definecolor{bgcolor3}{rgb}{0.972549, 0.74902, 0.792157}
\definecolor{bgcolor4}{rgb}{0.972549, 0.65098, 0.713725}
\definecolor{bgcolor5}{rgb}{0.964706, 0.513725, 0.631373}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5} \fill[bgcolor\i] (\i,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xcolor` (and, *shameless ad*, `xkcdcolors`) you can do this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xkcdcolors}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % well, really you can change xkcdCream with yellow!20!white, but...
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \yy using (100-(\i-1)*25)] in {1,...,5}
        \fill[xkcdCream!\yy!red] (\i,-1) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out is was my incompetence in `Inkscape` to import colors properly.
Using a color picker, picking the RGB values from screen and entering those manually worked like a charm.

Turns out the colors I wanted are

```
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor1}{0.996078  0.960784  0.964706}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor2}{0.980392  0.894118  0.901961}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor3}{0.968627  0.788235  0.792157}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor4}{0.968627  0.709804  0.721569}
\newrgbcolor{bgcolor5}{0.964706  0.6  0.643137}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\definecolor{bgcolor1}{rgb}{0.996078, 0.952941, 0.964706}
\definecolor{bgcolor2}{rgb}{0.980392, 0.882353, 0.905882}
\definecolor{bgcolor3}{rgb}{0.972549, 0.74902, 0.792157}
\definecolor{bgcolor4}{rgb}{0.972549, 0.65098, 0.713725}
\definecolor{bgcolor5}{rgb}{0.964706, 0.513725, 0.631373}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,1)
    \multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=2+1}{5}{\psframe*[linecolor=bgcolor\iA](\iA,0)(\iB,1)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]